# How to scale sparkline chart relative to cell height in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sparklines

In Google Sheets, the sparkline formula appears to fill a chart fully into a cell, whatever cell width and cell height is.

[image]

Is there any option to scale the chart height relative to the cell height, something like

> =sparkline(A1:A5,{"chartheight","50% of cell height"})

I have a very tall cell which stretches the chart unrealistically, which makes it harder to understand.  I have over 100 charts, which is also impractical to define ymin and ymax individually in each sparkline formula and all the charts have way different vales.

Comment: there is no such option, but you could maybe use linechart instead of in cell sparkline

Comment: What is controlling the height of the 'tall' cells (i.e. set manually/wrapped text/carriage returns)? I'm wondering if there's some sort of regularity in an adjacent cell which could potentially be exploited to set the sparkline ymax per chart in a semi-intelligent way.

Comment: @TheGodofBiscuits, the height of the cell is set manually to 185.